# Model.find is not a function in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, collections

I am new in node and mongodb. I am trying to query a different model(Event) from another model(Company).

Basically in `Event` model there is a field called `company`. I would like to get the company where id is an Event ID.

I have all the event IDs  in an array.

```
 let eventIds = [ 5b76a8139dc71a4a12564cd2,
  5b9a1685c239342d4635466c,
  5b8e753bdbccf803e906aaeb ]
```

**Event Schema** --

```
var EventSchema = new Schema({
        title:{type:String,require:true,index:true},
        description:{type:String,require:false},
        companies:[
            {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:"Company",require:true,index:true}
        ]
});
```

In company model --

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    Event = require('./event.js');

var CompanySchema = new Schema({
        name:{type:String,require:true,index:true},
        description:{type:String,require:false}},{
        //no auto indexing at the beginning
        autoIndex:true,

        //no strict to save changes in the valuesBeforeChange field.
        strict:false}
);

CompanySchema.static("searchCompanies",function(callback,criteria){

    "use strict";
    var That = this;
    var query = That.find();

    async.waterfall([

         function(callback){
             let eventIds =  [5b76a8139dc71a4a12564cd2,5b9a1685c239342d4635466c,5b8e753bdbccf803e906aaeb ];
             Event.find({ $in: eventIds}, function(err, docs){
                   console.log(docs);
             });
     }

],function(err,companyResultObj){
         callback(err,companyResultObj);
    });
});
```

I am getting `Event.find is not a function` error message. How can I query a different model(event) from another model(company)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post event schema

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Sure.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have updated the post with event schema.

Comment: You are missing to export your model. Add this line `export default Mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema)` or `module.exports = Mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema)`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Now getting `EventSchema is not defined` not defined.

Comment: You have to add in `EventSchema` file.

Comment: Yes it is added in `models/events.js`

Comment: Could you update your question where you did that.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure why but I had to do this in the following way.

```
Event.find({ $in: eventIds}, function(err, docs){
```

To

```
mongoose.model('Event').find({_id:eventIds}, function(err, docs){
```

which returned 3 documents which are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias when you require file

```
EventModel = require('./event.js');
then 
EventModel.find({ $in: eventIds}, function(err, docs){
   console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but not working.The error is `EventModel.find is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

How are you exporting your EventModel? 
Assuming you are exporting it like as a module (module.exports = { EventModel }),
you want to go "const Event = require('./event.js').EventModel;"

Then simply go with "Event.find(..."

Comment: If someone has the issue where this specific solution works, it's possible that you are using the wrong model.
Use the imported Model and not the one where you created the new entry with.

`const Shop = require('../models/shop');
const newShop = new Shop({..........});

newShop.find(); // won't work
Shop.find(); // will work`

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In my project I pass a Model into some middleware and started seeing this issue so I used mongoose.model('Name of Model')

example: .get(advancedResults(mongoose.model('Store'), 'stores'), getStores)

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing your model from an index.js or index.ts file, you had
better import the file as:

```
import YourModel from "./<file>/index"
```