# Mongoose model query(findById) error in hooks(pre middleware) due to foreign model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

In this case I have two models: Protocol and Comment. Each model has a middleware('pre' or 'remove') that calls the other model. Calling the Comment middleware in Comment.js stops at Protocol.findById() because Protocol is an object instead of a model function. 
Here is the console.log(Protocol) in Comment.js

```
Protocol : [object Object] Type : object
```

When `const Comment = require('../models/comment')` is removed in Protocol.js, then the Comment.js middlware works, and Protocol inside it is seen by the console as follow:

```
Protocol : function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
  model.hooks.execPreSync('createModel', doc);
  if (!(this instanceof model)) {
    return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
  }
  Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
} Type : function
```

I don't understant this behaviour. Moreover, in the other way around, the Protocol.js middleware works fine eventhough Comment.js has `const Protocol = require('../models/protocol')`

I found out a trick in [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478745/model-find-is-not-a-function-in-mongoose), which is to replace inside the middleware `Protocol.findById()` by `mongoose.model('Protocol').findById()`, but this doesn't explain the issue.

*Scripts are presented below. If you need more information please let me know and I'll provide it. Thanks*

**Protocol.js model & middleware**

```
// Dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

//Models
//<!---- If Comment is not required here then the Comment Middleware works ---->!
const Comment = require('../models/comment')

//Schema
const protocolSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title:  {
        type : String,
        required: true
    },
    comments : [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Comment',       
    }]
})

//Middleware Hook Call
protocolSchema.pre('remove', async function() { 
    console.log('Starts Protocol.schema.pre(\'remove\')')

    var toBeDeletedProtocol = this

    await removeComments()

    function removeComments(){
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('Starts removeComments()')
            var deletedComments = []

            Comment.find({protocol : toBeDeletedProtocol._id})
            .exec()
            .then( comments => {
                console.log('comments found: ' + comments)
                return resolve()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Removing comment(s) related to the deleted protocol failed in protocol remove Hook')
                return reject(err)
            })
        })
    }
}) 

//Model Export
module.exports = mongoose.model('Protocol', protocolSchema)
```

**Comment.js model & middleware**

```
//Dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

//Models
const Protocol = require('../models/protocol')

//Schema
const commentSchema =  mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        content: {
            type: String, 
            required : true
        },
        protocol : {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref : 'Protocol',
            required : true,
        }
    }
)

//Middleware Hook Call
commentSchema.pre('save', async function() {
    console.log('Starts Comment.schema.pre(\'save\')')

    var toBeSavedComment = this

    await updateProtocol()

    function updateProtocol(){
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('Starts updateProtocol()')

            console.log('toBeSavedComment : '+ toBeSavedComment) 
            console.log('Protocol : '+ Protocol, 'Type : ' + typeof Protocol)        
            //<!----- the ERROR occurs here -----!>
            Protocol.findById(toBeSavedComment.protocol)
            //<!----- Protocol is seen an object instead of a model function -----!>
            .exec()
            .then( protocol => {
                console.log('protocol found : ' + protocol)
                return resolve()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error in updateProtocol() in Comment.schema pre \'save\'') 
                console.log(err)
                return reject(err)
            })

        })
    } 

})    
//Export
module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema
```

)

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "debug",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, and I haven't face the same issue so far, so I still don't have a clear solution. But I now see a mistake that could possibly lead to this unexplained behavior. I was concatenating variables or objects in console.log, eg :

```
console.log('toBeSavedComment : '+ toBeSavedComment) 
console.log('Protocol : '+ Protocol, 'Type : ' + typeof Protocol)
```

Instead do use comma "," :

```
console.log('toBeSavedComment : ', toBeSavedComment) 
console.log('Protocol : ', Protocol, 'Type : ' , typeof Protocol)
```

Object concatenation in console.log, for instance, in Amazone Web Service: Elastic Beanstalk prevent the API compilation.

This is not real answer, but I hope this might help!